# LINQ to Entity Duplicate Record Issue

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am getting duplicate data in this query:

```
 var ids = Array.ConvertAll(categoryIds.Split(','), int.Parse);
 List<PublisherImage> images = db.DataModel.PublisherImages.Include("Categories")
    .Where(pi => pi.Enabled && pi.Rendered && pi.Categories
        .Any(c => ids.Contains(c.ID)))
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.OverallScore).ToList();
```

The duplicate data are the PublisherImages. I am new to all this and not sure why I am getting duplicate image records.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ids = Array.ConvertAll(categoryIds.Split(','), int.Parse);
 List<PublisherImage> images = db.DataModel.PublisherImages.Include("Categories")
.Where(pi => pi.Enabled && pi.Rendered && pi.Categories
    .Any(c => ids.Contains(c.ID)))
.OrderByDescending(i => i.OverallScore).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: just add .Distinct() befor .ToList();

Comment: I did try this before I posted this and for some reason it does not work at all.

Comment: what is the actual type of PublisherImage?

i mean for example student has some field like these: 

 - name
 - age
 - major
and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Entity Key` for your `PublisherImage` entity is not setup correctly in your model. The `Entity Key` must make your entity unique